# 4 pronged star to two Y resistor network

Tags: circuit-analysis, y-to-delta, delta-to-y

Is there any transform that relates four resistors meeting at a central node

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwNatC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

to a set of two Y resistors networks as shown below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff38XB.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be seen that the two circuits are NOT equivalent. Label the upper left hand corner 1, and the lower right hand corner 3. Leave the other corners open-circuit. The resistance from 1 to 3 in the upper diagram is 200 \$\Omega\$. The resistance from 1 to 3 in the lower diagram is 300 \$\Omega\$.

Furthermore, this cannot be fixed by changing the resistor values in the lower diagram. Label the upper right corner as 2. The resistance between 1 and 2 in the upper diagram is 200 \$\Omega\$. Which is the same as the resistance in the lower diagram. Changing the values of the resistors in the lower diagram will upset this equality.

Or, put another way, the values of resistances that make the lower diagram equivalent to the upper diagram is for R3 to equal 0, and the remaining resistors to equal 100 \$\Omega\$. Since R3 is equal to 0 in the lower diagram, it is trivially the same as the upper diagram.

Comment: Would it be possible for any particular resistances? As in, leaving the resistances unspecified, can we find any set of resistances that would allow this transformation? I have edited the question to remove the given values.

Comment: I made an addition to my post that answers the question you just asked.

Comment: Thanks for that, I added another question that hopefully you can answer.

Comment: I reverted your question back to its previous version. On this site, you should not make substantial changes to a question after it has been answered.

Comment: Please see a question I asked on your behalf https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/679266/268467

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the outer points P1 ... P4 (from top-left clockwise).

In the first circuit, if you apply a voltage between P1 and P3, then it works as a voltage divider composed of R1 and R3, and both P2 and P4 will see the same voltage.

If you do the same with the second circuit, you get a 3-element voltage divider composed of R1, R3, and R4. Now P2 and P4 are located at different steps of the divider, and only get the same voltage if R3 is zero - meaning that you effectively have the same circuit as before.

Answer (score 1):

the obvious answer is

```
R1'=R1
R2'=R2
R3'=0
R4'=R3
R5'=R4
```

where `Rn'` is the second circuit and `Rn`is thew first corcuit

That is just use 0 ohms  for the resistor the connects the upper and lower halves.

There is no transformation that converts back the other way (unless R3'=0).

Or in pictures:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSyXdz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: In the middle image, there is no voltage between the two marked points, which means there is also no current passing through that wire. Is it still equivalent if we remove that wire, or does it depend on outer resistances?

Comment: you can't get a useful answer by dividing by zero by zero.

Comment: What do you mean? For reference, I was talking about [this](https://i.imgur.com/4fvA2f1.png), the diagram states that all three circuits are equivalent. I'm wondering if it's true in general, or only for this specific case (hence the "or does it depend on outer resistances" part of my question)