# Physics diagram to electrical schematic

Tags: physics, network

After waiting a reasonable amount of time with no answer here, I have [duplicated this question at Physics Stack Exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/778746/290970).

---

I am asking this question on behalf of user furious.neutrino. This question may be more appropriate for physics stack exchange. If so, please feel free to migrate it.

The question is how to translate the following diagrams from the language of physics into electrical schematics.

[image]

The diagrams come from [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0308184.pdf)

The solid lines are easy to interpret.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNaw7n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I don't understand is how "the rest of the circuit" represented by the dotted lines are connected. In the left hand side, there are 4 terminals. In the right hand side, there are 6. Further, in the left hand physics diagram, are the dotted lines all connected? Or are they meant to cross without connection? That is, is the current in k1 supposed to equal the current in k3, and similarly for k2 and k4? Could someone complete "the rest of the circuit" for both diagrams?

Comment: Is this an attempt at a "4-way" delta-wye transform I wonder?

Comment: @brhans. I thinks so, but not sure. If there are restraints, such as I_k1 = I_k2, maybe an equivalence can be made. But to be honest, I am confused about the diagrams.

Comment: If the thick lines represent resistors, I wonder what the zig-zag staircase things are ... ?

Comment: The star-polygon (aka star-mesh) transform is more general than just the usual delta-wye transform. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-mesh_transform?useskin=vector.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I'll admit, I'm having a hard time understanding the diagrams in the question. It'd probably help to see them transformed into standard schematic diagrams.

Comment: @Hearth for N=4, there is no general inverse from a mesh to a star. If the mesh is a square with equal resistances R, diagonally related nodes have impedance R between them, while adjacent nodes have R||3R = (3/4)R impedance between them. A 4 pointed star can't do that.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes, the star-mesh transform only has an inverse in the special case of N=3. But it's unclear if you (or the person you're asking on behalf of) need an invertible transform or not.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy After skimming the paper, it brought back [Maldacena's *The Large N Limit of Superconformal Field Theories and Supergravity*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9711200.pdf), which is a seminal paper. Which then brought back Yang-Mills SU(N) gauge theory, Coxeter's Polytopes, and [Cartan subalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_subalgebra). I think that this really doesn't belong here because the context for the papers are important when relating them. I don't have the context. And I know I don't. Some there may.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy May as well add this paper: [The AdS/CFT Correspondence](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.00007.pdf). It may help clarify that aspect.

Comment: Can you help me out with the "why" part?  For example, what is voltage equivalent to in you diagram?  What would current mean?  We de electrical analogies of other systems all the time, but the differential equations underlying the system need to line up.

Comment: @ScottSeidman unfortunately, the only thing I understand is the resistances, because it is stated that the solid lines in the physics diagram correspond to resistances. After that, I am lost.

Comment: I do think that this seems like a physics question and not an electrical engineering question. The question concerns three topics: (1) Feynman diagrams as applied to whatever field of physics this is (I don't know enough physics to identify it); (2) circuit diagrams; and (3) the particular isomorphism between certain Feynman diagrams and certain circuit diagrams that's discussed in Gopakumar's paper. Electrical engineers are familiar with (2), but you need someone who's familiar with (1) and (3).